# Thujohn\Twitter\Twitter::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Config\Repository, instance of October\Rain\Config\Repository given

Tags: php, twitter, octobercms

How can I pass `Illuminate\Config\Repository` sentence instead of `October\Rain\Config\Repository`.

I'm try to use the thujohn twitter library. But the `Thujohn\Twitter` [`Constructor`](https://github.com/thujohn/twitter/blob/master/src/Thujohn/Twitter/Twitter.php#L58) has a reference to `Illuminate\Config\Repository`

In Plugin.php, boot() method, I have:

```
App::register(\Thujohn\Twitter\TwitterServiceProvider::class);
$alias = AliasLoader::getInstance();
$alias->alias('Twitter', \Thujohn\Twitter\Facades\Twitter::class);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change

```
use Illuminate\Config\Repository;
```

to

```
use October\Rain\Config\Repository;
```

in vendor packages main class file;

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad, but this change only work for a personal project, I need to work for a OC Plugin, that was installed from Marketplace.  My solution was to fork the repository and make it for OC.